# SKPhysicsJointFixed is not binding two nodes together

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, skphysicsjoint

I'm teaching myself swift while recuperating from back surgery and everyone's help has been awesome while I'm learning swift. I apologize if this seems super simple but I figure it might help the next guy.

I've read the [Apple Documentation on fixed joints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJoint_Ref/) and was struggling to get this to work.
[image]
You will notice that the joint is present but doesn't lock the two together.

This seems like a simple fix (and is) but hopefully this will help someone.
When you are adding your joint the documentation shows:
joint(**withBodyA**:bodyB:anchor:)
For this to work you need to make sure you enter in your sprite to be joined as the "withBodyA" body.

Answer (score 2):

My "bad" joint:

```
    let jointFixed = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(zombie1.physicsBody!, bodyB: zombie2.physicsBody!, anchor: z1.position)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(jointFixed)
```

The fix is to make sure the sprite you are joining to is the first variable:

```
    let jointFixed = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(zombie2.physicsBody!, bodyB: zombie1.physicsBody!, anchor: z1.position)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(jointFixed)
```

As always, triple reading the documentation is the key.